# How to find the cube root of 10 using Newton Raphson Method

Tags: newton-raphson

How to find the cube root of $10$ by Newton-Raphson method correct up to $5$ 
significant figures?

Comment: You choose a function for which $\sqrt[3]{10}$ is a root, make an initial guess as to what that root may be, then apply the method a couple of times. What is stopping you?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1):

Start by defining $f(x) = x^3 - 10$. By simple differentiation, $f'(x)=3x^2$.

You want to find the single real zero of $f(x)$.

You can start with an obvious initial estimate of $x_0=2$.

Now apply Newton-Raphson, which iteratively gives $x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$.

Do this until the last significant digit required stops changing.

Comment: Thanks. My final answer is 2.15443.

Comment: You might have taken one more sig fig than you need.